# NextJS <Image> component: Preload images before rendering them

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I want to preload images before programmatically rendering them.
Example:

```
      <Image
        src={
          color === "yellow"
            ? Yellow
            : color === "blue"
            ? Blue
            : Red
        }
        alt="color image"
        priority
        fill
        sizes="250px"
      />
```

If the default value for `color` is `"yellow"` the optimized Yellow image is being rendered on page load.

When changing the value of `color` to `"blue"`, via dropdown menu for example, the blue image is being loaded and rendered. That loading takes a while and thus the image is being displayed after a little delay.

How can I preload all three images Yellow, Blue and Red so they get displayed instantly when changing the value of `color` on page load without losing the benefits of the NextJS `<Image/>` component?

I tried using the `priority` and `loading` properties of the `<Image/>` component but they have no effect if the image is not supposed to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding three images for each color and setting the `display` property of the image wrappers to none:

```
    <ImageWrapper
      style={{
        display: "none",
      }}
    >
      <Image
        src={Yellow}
        alt="color image"
        priority
        fill
        sizes="250px"
      />
    </ImageWrapper>
```

This way each image is being loaded on page load and rendered instantly when conditionally changing the value of `color`